# Animation: Root of armature

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

[image][image]Picture a monkey climbinga a hanging wire, hand over hand, then take away the body, so only arms, the bone structure goes from on hand to the other. 
The root of the armature will be in one of the hands. 
It is easy to animate the first "hand over hand" motion, but when the "Root" hand need to move over the "free" hand/bone then I am struggeling. 
Is there a way to do so without messing up the motion?

Comment: The root of the armature will be in one of the hands? What do you mean, the root is generally placed under the character... Maybe show you've done so far

Comment: Yes, but I am not going to animate a monkey. My issue is that when an armature consisting of for example 3 bones The first one will e the root bone. When I have to move the root bone i would like the bone on the other end/bone to stand still. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Slinky motion"

Comment: Is there a way to not have a root maybe?

Comment: please show a picture (drawing) of how your armature looks like or what animation you want to create

Comment: Avoid asking a different problem that you think is related - if it's slinky it's slinky, not monkey arms. I think a bendy bones setup with work well, or a spline IK setup.

Comment: I have added a picture to try to explaine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - no slinky

Comment: Hehe, ok I am animating a robot with that acts like a monkey with no body. No natural place for the root. If I am to use armature for animating, I need the root to change from B to C when I animate C to D. I will add a new photo.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of frustrating ideas, I finally made it work.

I parented the objects to two armatures.

The first is Head up, and the second is Head down.

After animate the armatures, I swapped the visibility influence of the armatures in the Modifier Tab storing as keyframes.

I sent my file for analysis. Version 2.79b.
[image]

See the images below.

[image: Armatures setup]

[image: First frame of the animation]

[image: Animated armatures]

[image: Animated objects]

Comment: wow, congratulations, so it looks like it's impossible with only one armature?

Comment: Yeah! this was really helpful. Thanks!
Do you have a quick/smart way to copy the placement of armature 1 and 2 when you do the swap?